# maven jboss artifact issue

Tags: jboss, maven-3

Though http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/ seems to contain all the required JBOSS artifacts,

**Maven build complains**:

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/jboss-javaee-6.0/3.0.2.Final-redhat-13/jboss-javaee-6.0-3.0.2.Final-redhat-13.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/bom/eap/jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate/6.3.0.GA/jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate-6.3.0.GA.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project jbossEAP6Grp:jbossEAP6Art:1.0-SNAPSHOT (D:\personal\archetypes\jbossEAP6Art\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:3.0.2.Final-redhat-13 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) @ org.jboss.bom.eap:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools:[unknown-version], D:\unzipped\apache-maven-3.2.2\repository\org\jboss\bom\eap\jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools\6.3.0.GA\jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools-6.3.0.GA.pom, line 46, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.jboss.bom.eap:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate:pom:6.3.0.GA in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) @ line 105, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

**Snippet of Settings.xml**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
     <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
  <id>alwaysActiveProfile</id>
   <repositories>
   <repository>    
        <id>central</id>
  <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
  <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
</repository>
   .....
  <repository>
  <name>jboss-ga-repository</name>
                <id>jboss-products-ga-repo</id>
                <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>jboss-earlyaccess-repository</id>
                 <name>jboss-earlyaccess-repository</name>
                <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all/</url>
            </repository>       
   <repository>
  <id>ops4j</id>
  <name>ops4j</name>
  <url>http://repository.ops4j.org/maven2/</url>
</repository>
 </repositories>
</profile>
```

**Environment**

D:\unzipped\apache-maven-3.2.2\repository>cd /d D:\personal\archetypes\jbossEAP6Art> mvn -v

Apache Maven 3.2.2 (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e; 2014-06-17T19:21:42+05:30)

Maven home: D:\unzipped\apache-maven-3.2.2

Java version: 1.7.0_67, vendor: Oracle Corporation

Java home: D:\installed\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre

Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252

OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Do I need to add any other repositories or do I need to do something else?

Please advise